# ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Admincontroller does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have a website hosted in shared hosting space. After a long messy deployment, I tried to login into the system and now I am getting this error "ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Admincontroller does not exist". This persists in every route actions.

Already my public folder files are in public_html.

routes\web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'], 'prefix' => '/acumen'], function(){

    # index view for displaying admin section
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\Admincontroller@getIndexView')->name('admin.index');
```

I want the application working properly.

Comment: Post your `AdminController.php`. Does it have `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`? Is the class called `AdminController`?

Comment: and is the file called `AdminController.php`, not `admincONTROLLER.php` or any other capitalization? On Linux/Mac, the filename casing matters.

Comment: @TimLewis yes the namespace is correct the whole code worked properly on different environment after cloning. Just after deploying it in the server this problem started

Comment: How about the filename and class name? Are they `AdminController.php` and `class AdminController`? There's no weird case-sensitivity issue? We'd be able to verify if you posted your code/a screenshot of the contents of `App\Http\Controller\Admin`

Comment: @ceejayoz file names are absolutely correct i cross checked it multiple times

Comment: @TimLewis yes they are are same followed the naming conventions used  by laravel community.

Comment: Ok... Well I don't know then. You seem to have a lot of resistance to posting your code; not sure how to help.

Comment: @TimLewis yeah sure i will share the controller screen shot

Comment: Oh hang on, if your file is called `AdminController.php`, that's the issue. Your route file uses `Admincontroller`. Look at the casing.

Comment: Oh yeah; that's it. We're both looking right at it and still missing it. Woops. Yeah, fix the reference in `web.php` and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is `AdminController.php`, but your route definition says `Admin\Admincontroller@getIndexView`, so it's looking for `Admincontroller.php` instead, and not finding it.

This is pretty common for folks developing on Windows but deploying on case-sensitive Linux/Mac hosting. Fix your casing in the route definition and it should work; long-term, consider using something like Laravel Homestead to do your local development on a case-sensitive filesystem.